# Is there any surfing in West Mersea

Tags: surfing

I am going on holiday to West Mersea and wondered if there is any surfing?  I will be there in the summer months between June and July.

Comment: West Mersea in Essex, UK? Possibly not, but you may find surfing beaches relatively nearby eg https://www.surfertoday.com/surfing/the-best-surf-spots-near-london

Answer (score 5):

[This page](http://www.forces-of-nature.co.uk/dbdriven/beachguide/beachguide.php/location/387/west%20Mersea) says of West Mersea

- Surf Conditions at west Mersea are Not Good
- Buggying Conditions at west Mersea are Not Good
- Windsurfing Conditions at west Mersea can be Excellent
- Kitesurfing Conditions at west Mersea can be Excellent

West Mersea lies on the shore of an estuary. The wind can be brisk, but there is little open sea for large waves to build up, as the coast faces France, Belgium and The Netherlands across the North Sea, which are about 100 km away. This is distinct from the surfing in Cornwall where some of the coast faces the vast Atlantic Ocean and incoming waves can be surfed.